# Sentences lacking subject

Tags: grammaticality, ellipses

> *As shown above*, you can use this sentence.
>
> *When needed*, you can have this candy.
>
> You did more *than necessary*.

Those sentences have one thing in common. After word as, when, and than, they do not have subject. And it sounds perfectly normal. Can someone explain me why? Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm,  I’d say the subject of all three is ***you***

Comment: You should read : As it is shown above /  When it is needed / more than is/was necessary. The auxiliary and its subject (the impersonal pronoun "it") are just omitted.

Comment: What is auxiliary? And why is it not more than it is/was necessary? Can you explain?

Comment: And also, what rule allows you to omit these auxiliary and its subject?

Comment: The three most common auxiliary verbs (or helping verbs) are "be", "do" and "have". In this case, the auxiliary verb is "is". In the third sentence, I left the choice open between "is" and "was". The action being done in the past ("You did"), we don't know if the necessary things to be done were either specific to that precise moment or if it is something general that always need to be done in such circumstances. - *I am not sure that using the present (i.e. "is") can be accepted* -.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also tell me why these are omitted? and the name of the rule?

Answer (score 1):

The commas are a good initial indicator that those are distinct modifying phrases attached to subject-predicate pairs in the first two cases.

However, let's start with the third example, which is a little bit different:

> You did more than necessary.

That can be broken down into

```
You      did              more than necessary.
subject  transitive verb  object
```

We can pick apart `more than necessary` more than is necessary, but I think that's the essence of that one.

Let's take a look at the others.

> As shown above, you can use this sentence.

This is really the sentence

> You can use this sentence.

with a modifier hanging off the front of it.

You might ask what "as shown above" is modifying, and it's not immediately obvious.
Going by process of elimination, however, you can see fairly quickly that
`You` are not "as shown above", and `this sentence` is not "as shown above" -- those don't make much sense.
"As shown above" is an adverbial phrase modifying the compound verb "can use".

Similarly, your second example is just a case of "When needed" modifying "can have".

Answer (score 0):

In the first two sentences, the order is just switched around.

In each of your sentences the subject is

### you

> *You* can use this sentence as shown above

and

> *You* can have this candy when needed.

---

### Necessary is also a noun

Comment: I mean why it is not "as it is shown above" and just "as shown above" when no words in the  first clause  "you can use this sentence" repeat in second clause.

Comment: @haha - This clarification of your question is helpful!  You are right, "as shown above" is a shortened version of "as it is shown above."  Sorry, I don't know a name for this.  The reason the omission is possible is that the omitted words aren't needed to convey the intended idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the parts that you emphasised in italics are not classified as sentences. In English the usual minimum requirement for a sentence is that it,

(a) Starts with a capital letter

(b) Has a subject

(c) Has a verb

(d) Ends with a full stop (period)

Here is a sentence, "Dogs bark." It has all of the above requirements.

Your examples are all **subordinate clauses**.

> [subordinate clause](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=subordinate%20clause)
>
> noun
>
> a clause, typically introduced by a conjunction, that forms part of
>   and is dependent on a main clause (e.g. ‘when it rang’ in ‘she
>   answered the phone when it rang’).
>
> Google Dictionary